# Magento 1.9: Rewrite URL

Tags: url-rewriting, magento-1.9

I want to re-write URL in magento from

```
http://www.example.com/groupdeals/product/list/crc/14/
```

to

```
http://www.example.com/
```

Is there any way to convert it rather than using .htaccess ?
I tried using **URL Rewrite Management** in magento, but did not get success.
Please let me know the best possible solution to achieve this.
Thanks in advance

Comment: Read [this](https://www.addedbytes.com/articles/for-beginners/url-rewriting-for-beginners/), then add what web server you are running Magento 1.9 on.

Comment: @pzkpfw: apache web server

Comment: http://httpd.apache.org/docs/current/mod/mod_rewrite.html

Comment: @pzkpfw: thank you! merry christmas!!